# can't browse secure sites, not chrome firefox or opera

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser

I can't browse any secure site in Ubuntu 13.04. And I mean any site! Even when sites use somethings like Google analytics, HTTPS, CSS or JavaScript or something, I have to refresh sometimes to see the site.

For example, I can't visit gmail, but I can browse the same site on a Windows 8 machine running through qemu on this Ubuntu!

I could visit HTTPS sites before, but beginning some days ago, I can't.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your output of `date`? Do you have your computer updated? What happens when you open a site? Do you get an *error*?

Comment: `date` shows correct time, computer is updated and it just gives timout, for example on chromium, after a long wait, `Error code: ERR_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? What is your Internet connection? Have you tried using Tor?

Comment: I am behind a proxy (actually two options, two proxies, but none works). Tor doesn't connect, and I think it's because of HTTPS problem. I set proxy for Tor, also. I am using wifi. I use the same wifi and proxy for my android phone and there is no problem there...

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that you tried to manually set your IP and your gateway was set incorrectly on this particular machine. Did you use the GUI to set your IP or /etc/network/interfaces?

Try pinging another IP on your network and see if that validates. If you fail to ping out try pinging 127.0.0.1 or localhost to verify the card is working properly.

Other than those I'm stumped but I thought I'd give it my best shot.

Comment: no manual IP, and i say i can browse HTTP sites. I would check my IP and gateway with another computer on this network, but as far as I remember, this should be the configuration. BTW, could my problem relate to these? When I can browse HTTP?

Comment: I tried using another proxy server (STC, if you know that), but that even couldn't reach HTTPS sites...